JetBrains Rider removing space between delegate keyword and parenthesis
On my team, some of us use Rider, others use Visual Studio 2022. When they run code cleanup, VS 2022 adds a space between delegate and () as seen here:
var cat = this.ExecuteAFunction("Function Name Here", delegate () {});

On code cleanup in Rider, my code removes the space as seen here:
var cat = this.ExecuteAFunction("Function Name Here", delegate() {});

I have tried setting the 'Before Other Parentheses -> Method call parentheses' in Editor > Code Style > C#, but that adds it to all methods, not just delegate.
I've tried the other options under there, searched in the documentation about how these are set up and everything, and I cannot for the life of me figure out why Rider is doing this, but Visual Studio isn't. Before it's pointed out, no I cannot change delegate () {} to an arrow function per company coding standards.
Is there a setting I'm missing, an .editorconfig thing I should add, or something else that could fix this?

Couldn't you just do away with the parentheses?

@MathieuGuindon Sadly for the same reasons I can't use an arrow function, the parenthesis must remain.

The space doesn't make sense tbh, wish I could help.. good luck!

Yeah I know. It's more annoyance than anything, but I'd like the PR reviews to not include "why the space removal" all the time. Thanks, @MathieuGuindon!
